# Analysis of collision of a non-pivoted rod with a ball at one end?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision, inertial-frames

Suppose a a unpivoted rod in free space is struck by a ball at one end and we know the initial condition what will be the outcome of the collision?

Answer (score 0):

Easy. The rod will be rotating about its COM (actually, about all of its points with the same angular velocity, but the COM is a convenient point) and be translating with some velocity. Assuming the rod and ball to be a system, use three equations (conservation of linear and angular momentum and of kinetic energy) to find the three variables (velocities of rod and ball, and angular velocity of the rod).